# Comparison of classical and Zariski topologies with constructible sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-varieties

In David Mumford's book Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties the
proof of (3.25) **Specialization principle** on page 53 contains an argument
I not understand.

General assumptions: all our varieties are over $\mathbb{C}$. The statement is:

> (3.25) **Specialization principle.** Let $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m $
> be $r$-dimensionally subvariety and $X =p_1(Z) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ for
> $p_1: \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^n $. Suppose
> $\operatorname{dim} X=r $ and let
>
> $$\phi= \text{ res } p_1: Z \to X $$
>
> is almost everywhere (= on an open set) finite to one. [... ]
>
> Then the map
>
> $$ F: X_1 \to \mathbb{N}, x \mapsto \# \phi^{-1}(x)$$
>
> where
> $X_1 := \{x \in X \ \vert \ X \text{ smooth at } x \text{ and } \phi^{-1}(x) 
> \text{ finite } \}$ is *lower semi-continuous* in the *Zariski* topology on $X_1$.

Lower semi-continuous means that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set
$\{x \in X \ \vert \ \# \phi^{-1}(x) \ge n \}$ is closed.

The first part of the proof shows that $ F: X_1 \to \mathbb{N}$ is
*lower semi-continuous* in the *classical* topology, recall a smooth complex
variety can be canonically endowed with classical analytical topology
considering it as a complex manifold.

Mumford remarks that we can observe that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set
$\{x \in X \ \vert \ \# \phi^{-1}(x) \ge n \}$ is *constructible*, ie a union of finite
number of locally closed sets in Zariski topology.

Then Mumford claims that this implies that $F$ is
*lower semi-continuous* in the *Zariski* topology.

That's the point I not understand. Does anybody see
why the implication $F$ lower semi-continuous with resp classical topology
and that $\{x \in X \ \vert \ \# \phi^{-1}(x) \ge n \}$ is *constructible* imply
$F$ lower semi-continuous with resp Zariski topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for lower semi-continuity, we should consider sublevel set, i.e.
$$\{x\in X:\ \#\phi^{-1}(x)\leq n\}$$
Now, since $\#\phi^{-1}(x)$ is a constructible function, the above subset, denoted as A, satisfies that
\begin{equation}
A=\bigcup_{i=1}^N (Z_{i,1}-Z_{i,2})
\end{equation}
where $Z_{i,j}$'s are all Zariski closed subsets. Also, from the lower semi-continuity of $\#\phi^{-1}(x)$ in the classical topology, A is closed in the classical topology. Taking the classical closure of the above equation on $A$, we get
$$A=\bigcup_{i=1}^N Z_{i,1}$$
which is Zariski closed. This shows that $\#\phi^{-1}(x)$ is also lower semi-continuous in the Zariski topology.

Comment: do you maybe mean in your penultimate sentence that we take "Zariski closure" of $A$ and not "classical closure"? Indeed, since $A$ is assumed to be already closed in classical topology, the latter action would not change $A$, or do I missing your point?

Comment: @user267839 No, since A is classical closed when we take the classical closure of A, it is unchanged. But the right-hand side is changed when we take the classical closure, which is also Zariski closed. This leads to the Zariski closeness of A.